# build.gradle file does not access to gradle.properties

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle, gradle.properties

I have an android project. I am attempting to call `buildConfigField()` function in `build.gradle` file, but the property that I have declared in `gradle.properties` file cannot be found.

I have used this code in `gradle.properties`:

`ACCESS_KEY="access_key"`

and this code in `defaultConfig` block in `build.gradle` file:

`buildConfigField("String", "ACCESS_KEY", ACCESS_KEY)`

but the last parameter is unknown! I have selected that and pressed `ctrl + Q` on my keyboard, the message is No documentation found.

I have rebuilt and made my project but it still is not working!

Comment: You can't access Gradle properties like that. Try calling `getProperty('ACCESS_KEY')`.

Comment: I have the same issue. getPoperty is not working neither. But when I run "gradle properties" it is in the list. The thing works if the gradle.properties is in current dir but not when it is in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties. The gradle properties command shows it in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The double quote in the gradle.properties it not required.

```
ACCESS_KEY=access_key
```

Try to print the `ACCESS_KEY` in the gradle file and check your build console for the output of this:

```
print("Access key $ACCESS_KEY")
```

[image]

If you are using the Kotlin gradle script, you can get the gradle property values as below.

```
val ACCESS_KEY: String by project
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin DSL you can use like this

```
project.properties["BASE_API_URL"].toString()
```